# A variable changing without any apparent reason

Tags: python, class, variables

In my doctorate classes we were assigned to do a single neuron neural network that calculates OR, AND , XOR operations with a Python script. I have a very weird error that drives me crazy in my code.

First of all I have a Vector class:

```
class Vector3D:                                                                            # Defines the Vector3D class
    def __init__(self,bias,x,y):                                                           # Defines the variables for the Vector3D class
        self.bias = bias
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self,other):                                                               # Defines the built-in "add" ("+") operation for Vector3D
        return Vector3D(self.bias+other.bias,self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)
    def __mul__(self,other):                                                               # Defines the built-in "multipication" ("*") operation for Vector3D
        if(isinstance(other,int)):
            return Vector3D(self.bias * other, self.x * other, self.y * other)
        else:
            return Vector3D(self.bias * other.bias, self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)
    def __str__(self):                                                                     # Defines the built-in string return value for Vector3D
        return "Vector(%f,%f,%f)" % (self.bias, self.x, self.y)
    def UpdateWeights(self,eta, targetOutput, currentOutput, valueX, valueY, valueBias):   # Function for updating the weights
        self.bias = self.bias + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueBias)
        self.x = self.x + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueX)
        self.y = self.y + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueY)
        return Vector3D(self.bias,self.x, self.y)
    def getX(self):                                                                        # Function for getting the x value of a vector
        return self.x
    def getY(self):                                                                        # Function for getting the y value of a vector
        return self.y
    def getBias(self):                                                                     # Function for getting the bias value of a vector
        return self.bias
```

Secondly, I have a neuron class:

```
class Neuron:                                                                                   # Defines the Neuron class
    def __init__(self, dataTable, eta, theta, targetArrayOr, targetArrayAnd, targetArrayXor):    # Function for defining the variables for initialization
        self.dataTable = dataTable

        self.eta = eta
        self.theta = theta

        self.targetArrayOr = targetArrayOr
        self.targetArrayAnd = targetArrayAnd
        self.targetArrayXor = targetArrayXor

        self.wVbias = random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
        self.wVX = random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
        self.wVY = random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
        self.weightVector = Vector3D(self.wVbias,self.wVX,self.wVY)

        self.weightVectorOr = Vector3D(0,0,0)
        self.weightVectorAnd = Vector3D(0,0,0)
        self.weightVectorXor = Vector3D(0,0,0)

    def TrainForOr(self) :                                                                       # Function training the weight vector for OR operation
        iteration = 0                                                                            # Number of iterations
        check = 0                                                                                # Initial value of the while loop
        finalCheck = 200                                                                         # Final value of the while loop
        targetReached = False                                                                    # Boolean variable for if the target is reached
        rowNb = 0                                                                                # Initial value of the index number in the data table
        weightVector = self.weightVector                                                # Initial weight vector
        print(self.weightVector)
        while check < finalCheck :                                                               # Makes sure that the entire loop runs 200 times for accuracy
            while rowNb < len(self.dataTable) :                                                  # Makes sure every row is iterated
                while targetReached == False:
                    D1dotW = DotProduct(self.dataTable[rowNb],weightVector)                      # Dot product of the input vector and the weight vector
                    if(D1dotW > self.theta):
                        currentOutput = 1
                    elif(D1dotW <= self.theta):
                        currentOutput = 0
                    if(currentOutput == self.targetArrayOr[rowNb]):
                        targetReached = True
                    else:
                        iteration = iteration + 1
                        print(self.weightVector)
                        weightVector = weightVector.UpdateWeights(self.eta,self.targetArrayOr[rowNb], currentOutput, self.dataTable[rowNb].getX(), self.dataTable[rowNb].getY(), self.dataTable[rowNb].getBias())
                        print(self.weightVector)
                        targetReached = False


                targetReached = False
                rowNb = rowNb + 1

            check = check + 1
            rowNb = 0
        self.weightVectorOr = weightVector                                                       # Sets the OR weight vector
        return "OR - Final weight vector is " + str(weightVector) + " " + "("+ str(iteration) + " iteration(s) )"
```

I also have other methods for AND and XOR but they are the same with above with minor changes.

Now the above code "works" as the "error" is very minor and does not change the end result. But I want to understand why it happens.

When I run the above snippet along with the rest of the GUI code etc., I get the console result:

```
Vector(-0.051856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.051856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
Vector(-0.001856,-0.099352,0.079270)
```

This means that the initial `self.weightVector` is changing at the line:

```
weightVector = weightVector.UpdateWeights(self.eta,self.targetArrayOr[rowNb], currentOutput, self.dataTable[rowNb].getX(), self.dataTable[rowNb].getY(), self.dataTable[rowNb].getBias())
```

I don't understand this because I am not changing `self.weightVector` in any way in the `UpdateWeights` method.

If anyone can explain why this happens it will be appreciated.

Comment: "When I run the above snippet..." I don't see the snippet where you actually instantiate and use those classes. Could you please include this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UpdateWeights()` method modifies the vector.  This is why the vector changes when you call `UpdateWeights()`.

Here is a fixed version:

```
def UpdateWeights(self, eta, targetOutput, currentOutput,
                  valueX, valueY, valueBias):
    """Returns a new vector with updated weights."""
    bias = self.bias + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueBias)
    x = self.x + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueX)
    y = self.y + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueY)
    return Vector3D(bias, x, y)
```

P.S. Also note that documentation should go in docstrings, not comments.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this method:

```
def UpdateWeights(self,eta, targetOutput, currentOutput, valueX, valueY, valueBias):
    self.bias = self.bias + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueBias)
    self.x = self.x + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueX)
    self.y = self.y + (eta * (targetOutput - currentOutput) * valueY)
    return Vector3D(self.bias,self.x, self.y)
```

It not only returns a new `Vector3D` but also modifies itself (`self)`. And earlier you set:

```
weightVector = self.weightVector
```

So calling `weightVector.UpdateWeights` will cause altering the `self` of the same object.